# Visualforce page creation

Tags: visualforce, metadata

How can we Create a visualforce page which returns the list of Apex Classes, Triggers, Pages and Components based on the search entered in the text box.

Comment: Hi Jasmine, welcome to SFSE. the community can help if you can share what have you tried so far or if you have researched or gathered any info around this but couldn't proceed due to some errors. otherwise it will be too broad to answer such questions.

Comment: Jasmine it's not clear what you're trying to ask. Whether this is about 1) Creating a visualforce page, 2) getting apex classes in apex, 3) getting triggers in apex, 4) getting pages in apex, 5) getting components in apex. As you can see, that's potentially a lot of different questions. You'd help us by saying exactely which of these is the problem, and keeping your question limited to a single question. You can ask separate questions for different specific questions, that way it's easier to help you out.

Comment: Aside from the exact description you are suggesting, you may want to just download an IDE like the Force.com IDE or MavensMate.  It would depend on your use case.

Comment: or developer console

Answer (score 4):

Classes, Triggers, Pages and Components are stored in the database and can be queried like sObjects.  I assumed you could do it with SOSL but [apparently you can't](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l76mAAA), so you'd do it with SOQL instead.

```
String searchString = 'myQuery';
searchString = '%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchString) + '%';
List<ApexClass> matchingClasses = [SELECT Name FROM ApexClass WHERE Name LIKE :searchString];
List<ApexComponent> matchingComponents = [SELECT Name FROM ApexComponent WHERE Name LIKE :searchString];
```

...and so on, using the same approach to retrieve `ApexPage` and `ApexTrigger`.

You would then use a [pageBlockTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm) or [dataTable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm) to display the contents of `matchingClasses` and `matchingComponents` in your Visualforce page.

For further examples, see [SOQL for Apex class and VF Page](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hb7hAAA) and [Query for ApexClass?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/44979/query-for-apexclass) .

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using [apex-mdpai](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), a useful wrapper for the Metadata API.  You may have to test the permissions of your users who you want to see this page, though.